# How to subscribe PDF report from Power BI with multiple pages and send it on monthly basis?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to tell Power BI to automatically generate PDF file from a report with multiple pages and email it to users on a monthly basis?

I have a pro account.

Seems like its only possible to subscribe 1 page per subscription only with .PNG format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No PDF is not an option for the Power BI Service, It is only output in PDF format, and the report link. The limitions are outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-report-subscribe)

The only way to export with PDF via a subscription, is to use Power BI Premium and paginated reports. This supports PDF, PowerPoint, CSV, Excel and Word formats. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports-subscriptions)

Hope that answers your question.